# Why doesnt hasnext,hasprevious etc methods of Iterator or listIterator check for ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, collections

I know that failfast iterators check for ConcurrentModificationException on best-effort basis.Why doesnt the methods such as hasnext or hasPrevious check for ConcurrentModificationException  and throw it???

The following code works well for the precise reason that these methods are not checked for CME although it has been structurally modifed

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        List<String> lilong = new ArrayList<String>();
        lilong.add("Queen");
        for(Iterator<String> iter =lilong.iterator();iter.hasNext();)
        {
            System.out.println(iter.next());
            lilong.add("King");
            lilong.remove(0);
            lilong.add("Star");
            lilong.remove(0);
            lilong.add("Sun");
            lilong.remove(0);
            lilong.add("Polar Bear");
            lilong.clear();

            lilong.add("There you go");

        }
        System.out.println("size="+ lilong.size()+"##element##"+lilong.iterator().next());
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any iterators here.

Comment: The iterator is hidden in the for-each statement.

Comment: @Kayaman I mean [`iterator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#iterator()).

Comment: for each loop is internally inferred by compiler as iterator

Comment: Yes, for(String s : lilong) translates to code using lilong.iterator().

Comment: Alter your code to use the list object by 2 threads for modification and check if CME is thrown or not.

Comment: @Ravinder CME has nothing to do with threads, regardless of the "Concurrent" in the name.

Comment: It would not as long as hasnext method doesnt allow it to go inside the for each loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hasNext` for ArrayList's iterator *does not* check for modifications, it only looks at the size.

If you put one more element in your list, you'd get into a second iteration and then `next` would fail as expected.

As for why it is implemented that way...  +1 to your question.

Comment: yes but it could have checked using this method used by next() and remove() methods:-

 final void checkForComodification() {
            if (modCount != expectedModCount)
                throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        }
this is called from remove() and next() methods but not from hasnext() methods

Comment: "yes but it could have checked". True. But it does not.

Answer (score 1):

*Edit: Removed a load of crap*

So the question is: why doesn't `hasNext()` check for concurrent modification, like the other methods of Iterator.

If I would wager a guess, `hasNext()` doesn't have a lot of use unless there's a `next()` right after. So instead of having the check in 2 places, it's just in `next()`.

Comment: Yes.. that the point.Had it checked for concurrentmodification exception for hasNext() method,it could definitely have been good for this case also.Iterators check for CME only for next() and remove()

Comment: @AbhinavKumar I'm not actually sure what your code is trying to show. Even if hasNext() checked for CME, the example code would still run as it does now.

Comment: i need to replace my code for iterator construct,only then I would be clearer

Comment: yes they do but hasnext() bypasses this check.So I am wondering how will a CME will not be caught

Comment: Ah, I may have spoken a load of crap. The iterator won't detect modification if an element is replaced, but a remove/add should be detected.

Comment: "The iterator won't detect modification if an element is replaced". Sure it does.

Comment: ArrayList's javadoc says "merely setting the value of an element is not a structural modification.", so list.set(0, "foo") won't cause a CME. Oh wait, that's the part that talks about external modification, so it might still cause a CME. Nope, just tried it. The set(index, obj) method won't cause a CME.

Comment: I guess a single call to list.set(0,"foo") is different from two calls which add an element and then remove it because it is increasing the modification count by 2(mod-count becomes 3 in our case above).So calling hasnext() should have thrown CME

Comment: Yes, so an add/remove is detected, but a set() isn't (even though it could easily be...).