# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException not thrown when expected

Tags: java, exception

The following code throws a [java.util.ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html), as expected:

```
   public void test(){
      ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

      myList.add("String 1");
      myList.add("String 2");
      myList.add("String 3");
      myList.add("String 4");
      myList.add("String 5");

      for(String s : myList){
         if (s.equals("String 2")){
            myList.remove(s);
         }
      }
   }
```

However, the following code does *not* throw the Exception, while I expect it to be thrown:

```
   public void test(){
      ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

      myList.add("String 1");
      myList.add("String 2");
      myList.add("String 3");

      for(String s : myList){
         if (s.equals("String 2")){
            myList.remove(s);
         }
      }
   }
```

The difference is that the first list contains 5 items, while the second list contains 3. The JVM used is:

```
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)
```

The question: why does the second piece of code **NOT** throw the java.util.ConcurrentModificationException?

Comment: I have asked exactly same question.

Comment: Actually it is not the same question.  You asked why `remove` doesn't fail.  Different question, with a different answer.

Comment: (The reason that `remove` doesn't fail is because the test for concurrent modifications doesn't happen in that call!)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesnt hasnext,hasprevious etc methods of Iterator or listIterator check for ConcurrentModificationException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21450191/why-doesnt-hasnext-hasprevious-etc-methods-of-iterator-or-listiterator-check-for)

Comment: possible duplicate of [It does not throw exception ConcurrentModificationException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24556487/it-does-not-throw-exception-concurrentmodificationexception)

Comment: This is explained here https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4902078

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The iterator returned from `ArrayList.iterator()` in the implementation we're apparently both using only checks for structural modification in calls to `next()`, *not* in calls to `hasNext()`. The latter just looks like this (under Java 8):

```
public boolean hasNext() {
    return cursor != size;
}
```

So in your second case, the iterator "knows" that it's returned two elements, and that the list only *has* two elements... so `hasNext()` just returns false, and we never end up calling `next()` the third time.

I would view this as an implementation detail - basically the checking not being as strict as it could be. It would be entirely reasonable for `hasNext()` to perform a check and throw an exception in this case too.

Comment: In spite of the "disclaimer" in the javadoc for ArrayList, I'm not sure whether this isn't an oversight (bug), mainly because it isn't an unsynchronized structural change done from another thread. - The standard test checkForComodification() compares just two ints.

Comment: @laune - Whether or not it is an oversight, it is not a "bug" because the implementation is conforming to the spec.  Besides the code has been like this since (at least) Java 6.

Comment: @StephenC Does your "spec" have a link (other than ArrayList's javadoc)? (If a bug slips through more than one release then this doesn't make it sacrosanct.)

Comment: @laune Why wouldn't the ArrayList's javadoc be the spec? It specifies the behavior of ArrayList, including the fact that ConcurrentModificationException isn't reliable.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Why can't the confession be the commandment? I'm ready to concede that not all unsynchronized interactions can be detected anyway, but why on earth should the one and only List.remove() of element at index List.size()-2 go by undetected and result in skipping the last element whereas all other List.remove calls cause ConcModExc?

Comment: @laune: because if hasNext returns true, it will call next, which will detect the error.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry, but you've left me. If hasNext() returns false, you don't call next(), and the CME may remain undetected. This is what happens for any List.remove( List.size() - 2 )

Comment: @laune Whether it would be *better* for `hasNext` to make an attempt to detect concurrent modification doesn't change the fact that, per the class's specification, this behavior is not a bug. Perhaps the implementer had some performance concerns or just plain felt that the rarity of this scenario justified leaving the check out. Maybe they didn't think of it at all. Who knows? Either way, it's not a bug.

Comment: @laune: Yes, that's exactly my point - that's why it goes undetected, but others don't. If you were asking the more philosophical question of why it's implemented that way, Chris's comment says all I would say.

Answer (score 9):

Note also the last paragraph of the [ArrayList documentation summary](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

> Fail-fast iterators throw `ConcurrentModificationException` on a
>   best-effort basis. Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program
>   that depended on this exception for its correctness: *the fail-fast
>   behavior of iterators should be used only to detect bugs.*

If you're worrying about forcing lists to be read-only, use the `Collections.unmodifiableList` method, instead of checking for ConcurrentModificationException, which as mentioned above is not guaranteed to be thrown in all relevant cases.