# Why this code does not trigger ConcurrentModificationException?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, threadpoolexecutor

I'm modifying same list from multiple threads, shouldn't it trigger
ConcurrentModificationException while iterating list?

What could be done to trigger this exception?

```
public class ConcurrentTest {

    static List<String> list = setupList();

    public static List<String> setupList() {
        System.out.println("setup predefined list");

        List<String> l = new ArrayList();
        for(int i = 0; i < 50;i++) {
            l.add("test" + i);
        }

        return l;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);

        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            executorService.submit( () -> {     
                list.add("key1");       

                Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
                System.out.println( Thread.currentThread().getName() + ", " + list.size() );

                for(String val: list) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(25);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e) {

                    }
                }

            });
        }

        executorService.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does (and can) produce a `ConcurrentModificationException`. You are not catching it to print it.

With the below, we can see that it indeed throws many `ConcurrentModificationException`.

```
try {
    for (String val : list) {
        try {
          Thread.sleep(25);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**NOTE:** From the javadoc,

> Note that the fail-fast behavior of an iterator cannot be guaranteed
>     as it is, generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees in the
>     presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification.  Fail-fast iterators
>     throw {@code ConcurrentModificationException} on a best-effort basis.
>     Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program that depended on this
>     exception for its correctness:  the fail-fast behavior of iterators
>     should be used only to detect bugs

Also see: [java.util.ConcurrentModificationException not thrown when expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24980651/java-util-concurrentmodificationexception-not-thrown-when-expected)

---

Or, you could get the returned `Future` and collect them in a list. By doing that, you will get the exception when calling `get` on (atleast) one of the futures.

Answer (score 1):

The ConcurrentModificationException triggers when you modify a list while iterating on it. In your code qhen you iterate on the list, you only sleep the thread and do not modify it.This would trigger the exception:

```
for(String s: list) {
    list.add("something");
}
```

Comment: This is not true. The *same* list is being modified from other threads

Answer (score 1):

Have you check whether below block throwing exception or not.

```
try {
    list.add("key1");       

    Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
    System.out.println( Thread.currentThread().getName() + ", " + list.size() );

    for(String val: list) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(25);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {

        }
    }
}catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Please wrap around try...catch block and print() error message to check its throwing error or not.